# MAX4466 recording sound

Tags: audio

on my current project I'd like to record sound and store it as a .wav file.
I already have a MAX4466 Microphone Amplifier bute when it comes to the hardware, I need some adivce.
For recording audio, do I need an ADC (any recommendations) or maybe some more components?

Comment: Raspberry Pi has no ADC onboard. if you are interested in sound, you might need one =)

Comment: Would an ADC be enough or would I need an external sound card as well, any other components?